# Convert RGB surface to YUV in hardware using Direct3D 9

Tags: c++, c, windows, directx, direct3d

I have an `ARGB Direct3D9` surface that I need to blit into `UYVY` surface of the same dimensions. Both surfaces are in system memory. How can I accomplish this?

> UpdateSurface and StretchRect fail.

I'm open to using textures instead of surfaces if needed.

This must be done in GPU, i.e. with hardware acceleration.

Comment: Why are you using legacy Direct3D 9? DirectX 11 is a better choice for all Direct3D development, and DirectX 11 Video is generally better integrated with Direct3D than older APIs.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this task in DX 11?

Answer (score 0):

In [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) there is code for doing all these conversions you could look at for reference. The legacy Direct3D 9 `D3DFMT_UYVY` format is the same as `DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2` with some channel swizzling.

These formats encode two visible pixels in each image pixel:

```
struct XMUBYTEN4 { // DirectXMath data type
  uint8_t x;
  uint8_t y;
  uint8_t z;
  uint8_t w;
};

XMUBYTEN4 rgb1, rgb2 = // Input pixel pair

int y0 = ((66 * rgb1.x + 129 * rgb1.y + 25 * rgb1.z + 128) >> 8) + 16;
int u0 = ((-38 * rgb1.x - 74 * rgb1.y + 112 * rgb1.z + 128) >> 8) + 128;
int v0 = ((112 * rgb1.x - 94 * rgb1.y - 18 * rgb1.z + 128) >> 8) + 128;

int y1 = ((66 * rgb2.x + 129 * rgb2.y + 25 * rgb2.z + 128) >> 8) + 16;
int u1 = ((-38 * rgb2.x - 74 * rgb2.y + 112 * rgb2.z + 128) >> 8) + 128;
int v1 = ((112 * rgb2.x - 94 * rgb2.y - 18 * rgb2.z + 128) >> 8) + 128;
```

For `DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2` you would use:

```
XMUBYTEN4 *dPtr = // Output pixel pair

dPtr->x = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>(y0, 0), 255));
dPtr->y = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>((u0 + u1) >> 1, 0), 255));
dPtr->z = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>(y1, 0), 255));
dPtr->w = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>((v0 + v1) >> 1, 0), 255));
```

For `D3DFMT_UYVY` you would use:

```
dPtr->x = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>((u0 + u1) >> 1, 0), 255));
dPtr->y = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>(y0, 0), 255));
dPtr->z = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>((v0 + v1) >> 1, 0), 255));
dPtr->w = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min<int>(std::max<int>(y1, 0), 255));
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I need it to be done on GPU side, i.e. with hardware acceleration, that's why this is not an option. I'll update the question

Comment: If the surface is in system memory, you can't do it on the GPU.

Comment: What if I copy it to surface that is in VRAM? Can I do something then?

Comment: The point is that if it's already in system memory, it may well be faster to do on the CPU. Uploading the data to and from VRAM takes time, and you haven't described how you intend to use the result. In any case, your options are limited in doing it in Direct3D 9 due to the HLSL limitations of the older Shader Models. Full precision integer support isn't really there until Shader Model 4.0 which means you'd be better off using Direct3D 11.